# When app is opened from deep link, the app should be opened from the beginning and not from from where it was left off- flutter

Tags: flutter, deep-linking

When the app is running in the background and the deep link is clicked it continues from where it was in the background. How should I start the app from the beginning in flutter?

(Should have only one instance)

Thanks

Comment: It would be better if you provide some code and the research / experiments that you've already done in this regard, so we have more information.

Answer (score 0):

create a navigator key:

```
GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey();
```

then in the onGenerate use the key to pop until the desired page.

```
 navigatorKey.currentState!.popUntil(((route) => route.isFirst));
```